# how do i fix error fdisk:cannot open /dev/sdb: Input/output error

Tags: error-handling

i am trying to create a partition but am unable due to error:

[image]

Comment: An IO error on a device is usually an issue with hardware, be it cables, power or the device itself is dying... You've provided no OS/release details thus we can only be generic, and we don't even know what type of device; but if it's a disk/ssd then I'd suggest checking the device health using SMART (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)

Comment: You can run `fsck` on a disk (`/dev/sdb`) ONLY if  neither it, nor any of it's partitions [if they exist) is `mount`ed.

Comment: Verify that you actually have a disk connected that ends up as `/dev/sdb` - `$ lsblk -ape7` will tell.

Comment: Do you have a file-system on device `sdb`.  Such a case used to be common in the 1980s, but the more modern DOS (thus windows) & GNU/Linux by default create a partition table and thus have partitions where the file-system is stored in the partitions (ie. sdb1, sdb2 etc).  Your issue maybe *operator error* due to attempting to file-system check a device and not a partition where file-system actually exists.